# flipping a coin repeatedly

Tags: probability-theory

A biased coin $P(H) = p$ (and $P(T) = q$) is tossed repeatedly, let X be the length of the first run and Y be the length of the second run.  A run is a maximal sequence of consecutive heads or consecutive tails.  For example HHHTT is a run of 3 heads followed by a run of 2 tails.  Find the $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$.

The way i solved it is:
$$p E(\text{number of flips until first T}) + q E(\text{number of flips until first head})$$

I calculated that the $E(\text{number of flips until first T}) = 1/q$    and $E(\text{number of flips until first head}) = 1/p$

this gave me $E(X) = (p/q) + (q/p)$

However, i am not sure how to calculate $E(Y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The probability that the second run starts with a tail is $p$, and the probability that it starts with a head is $q$. This is because the second run starts with a tail precisely if the very first toss was a head.

Then use your basic method.